Maps used as context using contextily doesn't match with basemap
Both sources use the the same WGS84 Web Mercator projection, but the maps doesn't match:
import contextily as cx
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from mpl_toolkits.basemap import Basemap


# Map source
source = cx.providers.OpenStreetMap.Mapnik

# Plot
fig, ax = plt.subplots(figsize=(10, 10))

m = Basemap(
    projection="merc",  # Mercator-Projektion
    epsg=3857,          # WGS84 Web Mercator
    llcrnrlat=44.82,
    urcrnrlat=55.30,
    llcrnrlon=5.89,
    urcrnrlon=15.56,
    resolution="i",
    ax=ax,
)
m.drawcoastlines()

# Add context-basemap
cx.add_basemap(ax, crs="EPSG:3857", source=source)

# Show
plt.show()

Has anyone an explanation..?
In the image, they're not correctly adjusted:

